# Where do I list racial traits/class abilities on a PF character sheet?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-sheets

So let's say that I pick a half-orc which has traits such as orc vision and orc ferocity, etc. Would they be written in the 'Special Abilities' part of the character sheet?

Another thing is on the table that tells a class's BAB and saving throws, and so on. There is a column labeled 'Special'. Where do those things get listed?

Comment: There's about a billion different character sheets, which one do you mean?  The one in the back of the Core Rulebook?  The Pathfinder Society one? Etc?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you would put all class and racial abilities under the *Special Abilities* column.** Furthermore, anything under the *Special* column on a class description chart would be recorded or updated under the *Special Abilities* column when you gained them, unless you have memorized certain mundane abilities, such as [*Fighters' Bonus Feat*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/fighter#TOC-Bonus-Feats), that only matter when you level up